# A question about input of snakemake workflow

Tags: snakemake

I meet a question in writting snakemake.
As we know, snakemake link each rule by input&output file.
But I meet a situation:

```
rule index:
    input:
        fastq,
        blow5
    output:
        slow5.idx
    threads:8
    shell:
        "f5c index --slow5 {input[1]} {input[0]}"

rule estimate:
    input:
        fastq,
        bam,
        ref
    output:
        results.tsv
    threads:8
    shell:
        "nanopolish polya --reads {input[0]} --bam {input[1]} --genome {input[2]} > {output}"
```

The below show that the ouput .idx in rule index can not be used as an input for rule estimate ( for the reason that nanopolish doesn't offer a place for idx although it really need a idx file).
So I need to run 'rule index' at top, but there is no output of 'rule index' can be used as input for other rule.
I want to run this rule index, so I put .idx file in rule all, trying to run it by perserving output through 'rule all'.
But I met

```
MissingOutputException in rule slow_index in file XXX.py, line 30:
Job 1  completed successfully, but some output files are missing. Missing files after 180 seconds. This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait:
slow5.idx
```

This time I have changed '--latency-wait' but it still doesn't work.
Can everybody solve that?
Thank you!

I wanna  receive the solution of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can still include the output of rule index for rule estimate even though you dont use it. This way snakemake knows which rule goes first.

```
rule estimate:
    input:
        fastq,
        bam,
        ref,
        rules.index.output[0]
    output:
        results.tsv
    threads:8
    shell:
        "nanopolish polya --reads {input[0]} --bam {input[1]} --genome {input[2]} > {output}"
```